# Strange lexing issue keywords vs identifiers regex matching

Tags: flex-lexer

I've been struggling to understand some behavior of flex.

I started defining a small toy-like example program which will tokenize into keywords and strings.

One definition of the regex performs as expected but another behaves quite differently, contrary to my expectation.

It has been a few years since I've played with this stuff so hopefully someone can point me in the right direction.

I modified the token regular expression to get it to work but I'd really like to understand *why* my original choice behaved differently.

This first example is the non-working code

```c
%{
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
%}
%option noyywrap
%%
[ \t\n]                   {cout << "ws" << endl;};
buzz                      {cout << "kw" << endl;};
[^\n]+                    {cout << "str" << endl;};
%%
int main(){
yylex();
}
```

The second example is the modified version which does behave properly.

```c
%{
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
%}
%option noyywrap
%%
[ \t\n]                   {cout << "ws" << endl;};
buzz                      {cout << "kw" << endl;};
[a-zA-Z]+                 {cout << "str" << endl;};
%%
int main(){
yylex();
}
```

In the code, buzz is supposed to be a keyword, and anything following should be just read as a string.

For the first example, buzz gets consumed up along with the remaining word as a "str".

In the second example, buzz is properly recognized and the remaining word becomes the "str".

I understand that the third rule in both cases is also a valid definition for a token containing the characters b-u-z-z. Each of these four letters is in [^\n]+, as well as [a-zA-Z]+. So why on earth is the behavior different?

example inputs would be:

```
buzz lightyear
buzz aldren
```

Thanks!

Comment: Okay I guess it's because [^\n] includes space. Perhaps someone could help me figure out a way to read from the buzz keyword until the end of the line, including *anything* but the newline.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Flex (as well as most other lexer generators) works according to the maximum munch rule. That rule says that if multiple patterns can match on the current input, the one that produces the longest match is chosen. If multiple pattern produce a match of the same size, the one that appears first in the .l file is chosen.

So in your working solution the patterns `buzz` and `[a-zA-Z0-9]+` both match `buzz`, so `buzz` is chosen because it appears first in the file (if you switched the two lines, `str` would be printed instead). In your non-working solution `buzz` still would only match `buzz`, but `[^\n]+` matches `buzz lightyear` and `buzz aldren` respectively, which is the longer match. Thus it wins according to the maximum munch rule.